# Load JSON content from a local file with http.get() in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, http

I'm trying to load a local JSON file with `http.get()` in Angular 2. I tried something that I found here on Stack Overflow. It looks like this:

This is my `app.module.ts` where I `import` the `HttpModule` and the `JsonModule` from `@angular/http`:

```javascript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavCompComponent } from './nav-comp/nav-comp.component';
import { NavItemCompComponent } from './nav-comp/nav-item-comp/nav-item-comp.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavCompComponent,
        NavItemCompComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

In my **component**, I `import` `Http` and `Response` from `@angular/http`. Then I have a function called `loadNavItems()`, where I try to load my JSON content with a relative path using `http.get()` and print the result with `console.log()`. The function is called in `ngOnInit()`:

```javascript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-nav-comp',
    templateUrl: './nav-comp.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./nav-comp.component.scss']
})
export class NavCompComponent implements OnInit {

    navItems: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadNavItems();
    }

    loadNavItems() {
        this.navItems = this.http.get("../data/navItems.json");
        console.log(this.navItems);
    }
}
```

My **local JSON file** looks like this:

```javascript
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Home",
        "routerLink": "/home-comp"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "&Uuml;ber uns",
        "routerLink": "/about-us-comp"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Events",
        "routerLink": "/events-comp"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Galerie",
        "routerLink": "/galery-comp"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Sponsoren",
        "routerLink": "/sponsoring-comp"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Kontakt",
        "routerLink": "/contact-comp"
    }
]
```

There aren't any errors in the console, and I just get this output:

[image]

In my **HTML template** I would like to loop the items like this:

```html
<app-nav-item-comp *ngFor="let item of navItems" [item]="item"></app-nav-item-comp>
```

I made this with a solution I found here on Stack Overflow, but why doesn't it work?

***Edit relative path*:**

I also get a problem with my relative path, but I'm sure it's the right one when I use `../data/navItems.json`. In the screenshot, you can see the *nav-comp.component.ts* file, where I load the JSON content using a relative path from the JSON file which is in the folder called data? What's wrong? Does the console print an 404 error, because it can't find my JSON file from the relative path?

[image]

Comment: I found my own solution and post it below (marked as correct answer). Thanks again.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but bit different. I have a image in assets folder. And i have a property of type `File` in my service. I want to read that Image in my assets into a `File` type Object.Can you help achieving this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***My own solution***

I created a new `component` called `test` in this folder:

[image]

I also created a mock called `test.json` in the `assets` folder created by `angular cli` (important):

[image]

This mock looks like this:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Item 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Item 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Item 3"
        }
]
```

In the controller of my component `test`, `import` follow `rxjs` like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

This is important, because you have to `map` your `response` from the HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) call, so you get JSON content and can loop it in your `ngFor`. Here is my code how I load the mock data. I used `http` `get` and called my path to the mock with this path `this.http.get("/assets/mock/test/test.json")`. After this I `map` the response and `subscribe` it. Then I assign it to my variable `items` and loop it with `ngFor` in my `template`. I also export the type. Here is my whole controller code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

export type Item = { id: number, name: string };

@Component({
  selector: "test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.scss"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Array<Item>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get("/assets/mock/test/test.json")
      .map(data => data.json() as Array<Item>)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.items = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

And my loop in its `template`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

It works as expected! I can now add more mock files in the assets folder and just change the path to get it as `json`. Notice that you have also to import the `HTTP` and `Response` in your controller. The same in you app.module.ts (main) like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './components/molecules/test/test.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: .map(data => data.json() as Array<Item>)

This line tells me that Object does not have method 'json'

Comment: @RanLottem Do you export the type "Item" correctly?

Comment: Regardless of the type I cast into in this line, data.json() still gives an error that 'Object' doesn't have a json property.

Comment: the default get returns json, no need to do .json()

Answer (score 96):

For **Angular 5+**, only perform steps **1** and **4**

---

In order to access your file locally in **Angular 2+** you should do the following (4 steps):

**[1]** Inside your assets folder create a *.json* file, example: **data.json**

**[2]** Go to your *angular.cli.json* (angular.json in Angular 6+) inside your project and inside the **assets** array put another object (after the *package.json* object) like this:

{ "glob": "data.json", "input": "./", "output": "./assets/" }

**full example from angular.cli.json**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        { "glob": "package.json", "input": "../", "output": "./assets/" },
        { "glob": "data.json", "input": "./", "output": "./assets/" }
      ],
```

Remember, *data.json* is just the example file we've previously added in the assets folder (you can name your file whatever you want to)

**[3]** Try to access your file via localhost. It should be visible within this address, http://localhost:your_port/assets/data.json

If it's **not visible** then you've done something incorrectly. Make sure you can access it by typing it in the URL field in your browser before proceeding to step #4.

**[4]** Now preform a GET request to retrieve your *.json* file (you've got your full path *.json* URL and it should be simple)

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
        // Make the HTTP request:
        this.http.get('http://localhost:port/assets/data.json')
                 .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Hi Eugen, I will try it later, hope this works! Thanks

Comment: I will try it today and inform you.

Comment: It seems to work. But my json stuff is in _body. Is this correct?

Comment: And I can't loop the result in my ngFor, follow error: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Home"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "About us"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Contact"
        }
    ]
}
' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to`

Comment: I found my own solution and post it below (marked as correct answer). Thanks again.

Comment: What if I don't want to put that file into assets?

Comment: @kingforever where would you want to put it? assets file is intended for such scenarios.

Comment: @eugne_sunic I have another data folder for my component where I want to put all my component level JSON files and I want to put only shared service's JSON files into asset folder.

Comment: In Angular 5, all you need to do is to place the .json file under assets folder, as mentioned in step 1 and reference it directly in your service call, as mentioned in step 4.
It works for me.

Comment: Mano is correct.  In newer versions of Angular no need to change angular.json.  Just put the json in assets and it will work.  If someone could edit the answer with this that would be great.  I didn't see this comment until after I started the steps above.

Comment: I don't think that assets are the only way of reading local file adding, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940939/806202

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 16):

You have to change

```
loadNavItems() {
    this.navItems = this.http.get("../data/navItems.json");
    console.log(this.navItems);
}
```

to

```
loadNavItems() {
    this.navItems = this.http.get("../data/navItems.json")
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .do(data => console.log(data));
                    // This is optional. You can remove the last line
                    // if you don't want to log the loaded JSON file 
                    // in the console.
}
```

Because `this.http.get` returns an `Observable<Response>` and you don't want the response, you want its content.

The `console.log` shows you an observable, which is correct because navItems contains an `Observable<Response>`.

In order to get data properly in your template, you should use an `async` pipe.

```
<app-nav-item-comp *ngFor="let item of navItems | async" [item]="item"></app-nav-item-comp>
```

This should work well. For more information, please refer to the [HTTP Client documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html).

Comment: "Property map does not exist on type Observable<Response>" ?

Comment: I imported "import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';", the error isn't there anymore but the output in the console is the same?

Comment: add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` in your imports, or `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';` and change `navItems: any` for `navItems:Observable<any>`

Comment: @MrBuggy if you want to have an input to the console, I can edit the answer to add one, but I thought your main issue was to render the content in your template so I removed the console.log.

Comment: @MrBuggy I added console.log to the observable chain using `do` oprtator, you can add it if you want to console.log received data.

Comment: Now I got a problem with my relative path, but I'm pretty sure, that my path isn't wrong? Please look at my edited question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144536/discussion-between-supamiu-and-mrbuggy).

Comment: This issue solves the path problem: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1309

Comment: I found my own solution and post it below (marked as correct answer). Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

I found that the ***simplest*** way to achieve this is by adding the *file.json* file under folder *assets*.

There isn't *any* need to edit file *.angular-cli.json*.

#### `Service`

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  getJsonData(): Promise<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json').toPromise();
  }
}
```

#### `Component`

```
private data: any[];

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    data = [];
    this.dataService.getJsonData()
      .then( result => {
        console.log('ALL Data: ', result);
        data = result;
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log('Error Getting Data: ', error);
      });
  }
```

###Extra:

Ideally, you only want to have this in a development environment, so to be bulletproof, create a variable on your *environment.ts* file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseAPIUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json'
};
```

Then replace the URL on the *http.get* for *`${environment.baseAPIUrl}`*.

And the *environment.prod.ts* file can have the production API URL.

Answer (score 5):

Put your *navItems.json* file in the "assets" folder. Angular knows how to look inside the assets folder. So instead of:

```
loadNavItems() {
    this.navItems = this.http.get("../data/navItems.json");
    console.log(this.navItems);
}
```

Change the path to simply:

```
loadNavItems() {
    this.navItems = this.http.get("assets/navItems.json");
    console.log(this.navItems);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Philip for your calm advice.. it helped me out :-)

Answer (score 1):

- create/move the JSON file under folder `assets`
- implement a method in the service

  ```
  private URL = './assets/navItems.json'; // ./ is important!

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  fetch(): Observable<any> {
      return this.httpClient.get(this.URL);
  }
  ```
- call it in component

  ```
  private navItems: NavItems[];

  constructor(private navItemsService: NavItemsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.publicationService.fetch().subscribe(navItems => this.navItems = navItems);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the response of the request in the `navItems`. Because `http.get()` returns an observable, you will have to subscribe to it.

Look at this example:

```js
// Version without map
this.http.get("../data/navItems.json")
    .subscribe((success) => {
      this.navItems = success.json();
    });

// With map
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
this.http.get("../data/navItems.json")
    .map((data) => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .subscribe((success) => {
      this.navItems = success;
    });
```

Comment: This is another way to solve the problem yes, I mainly use async pipe to avoid using variables just to store results. Also, async pipe is better to me because it will unsubscribe for you, meaning that you'll avoid memory leaks if you have observables that are persistent across pages (services for example).

Comment: I agree. It's a easier way to solve and understand the problem but at the end I will you use your solution.

Comment: I found my own solution and post it below (marked as correct answer). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Angular CLI: 7.3.3`: In the assets folder, put fake JSON data and then on services, just do this:

`const API_URL = './assets/data/db.json';`

```
getAllPassengers(): Observable<PassengersInt[]> {
  return this.http.get<PassengersInt[]>(API_URL);
}
```

[image]