# Angular 4: How to read content of text file with HTTPClient

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a .txt file in my Angular 4 project directory and I want to read its content. How to do it ? Below is the code which I employed.

The file is in 'files' folder which is inside the 'app' folder. 
The component where i have HTTPClient code is in 'httpclient' folder which is inside 'app' folder.

Meaning 'files' folder and 'httpclient' folder are children.

The code is shown below. It not working as i m getting 404 error - 'GET http://localhost:4200/files/1.txt 404 (Not Found)'

```
this.http.get('/files/1.txt').subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
                console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
            } else {
                // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
                // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
                console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried a relative URL? (i.e. `http.get('files/1.txt')` -- no initial slash) Or placing the files in the `assets` folder, the content of which - I believe - is copied as is at the root of the site.

Comment: yes i tried it just now, same error. It is not finding it - 404. what's wrong? I am just following the codes of official angular docs https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Comment: your file path is correct ?

Comment: yes file path is correct. Even if i move the text file to the same folder of teh component and do this.http.get('./1.txt') i get the same error.

Comment: It works if you place the text file in `assets` and do `http.get('/assets/textfile.txt')`.

Comment: @AngularChef keeping in asssts do work. But why its not working when keeping in separate folder.

Comment: @yogihosting can you share file structure of 1.txt document. like app => home => 1.txt ?

Comment: @Chandru its not working see this code this.http.get('app/files/1.txt', {responseType: 'text'}) its not working - getting 404 here.

Comment: @yogihosting it's not working because when the CLI builds the project with `ng serve` it only processes .ts, .html and .css files. Static assets like .txt files do not belong in your code and they are dropped by `ng serve`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try like this :

```
this.http.get('app/files/1.txt').subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.text());
})
```

The CLI can't access docments inside the app directory your project. if you move to text document you can access the text file like `assets/1.txt`.

if you want to access document inside the app directory you need to add path in assets array in the **.angular-cli.json**

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "app", /* add this line to access document inside the app directory */
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

here below is my example try like this :

```
this.http.get('app/home/1.txt').subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data', data.text());
})
```

Comment: Yes assets files are accessible but How I can assess files kept in separate folder?

Comment: you need to add `app` in the angular-cli.json file inside the assets array . then you can access it. and import is re-run the project

Comment: I added app to the angular-cli.json, its still not working.

Comment: @yogihosting After add `app` inside the assets array. you need to Re-run the project or Restart the project

Comment: you are just great! I have to restart my angular project. I was using vs code. So i closed it and reopened it and ran the app once more. Now I am able to asses it. The code here is this.http.get('app/files/1.txt', {responseType: 'text'})

Answer (score 24):

Angular 6/7

> { responseType: 'text' as 'json'}

for now works

```
this.http.get("app/files/1.txt", { responseType: 'text' as 'json'}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.text());
})
```

Refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586) on GitHub for the complete discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Just one correction to the previous answer: 
add "responseType: 'text'" to the options:

```
this.http.get("app/files/1.txt", "{ responseType: 'text' }").subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.text());
})
```

Comment: Here, in January 2020, text() method must be removed... if so, this code works.

Answer (score 3):

This is tested in `Angular 6`

Create a service using

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
//Read  text file
export interface ResultJson{

}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
  urlEncoded = '/Test.text';
  getText(){
    return this.http.get(this.urlEncoded, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
}
```

and call the service in your component like below

```
  resultJSON: ResultJson;
  ResultJsonString : any;
this
    .testService
    .getText()
    .subscribe((data:ResultJson) => {
         this.ResultJsonString = data;
       });
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a local file(JSON) with **Angular 6** project.

Project strucuture:

```
|-src
|--app
|---core
|---...
|---app.module.ts
|--assets
|...
```

Steps:

1) Inside `angular.json` I've added the folder where I put the file:

```
 "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src", // ** my project root is "src" folder
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            // ...
            "assets": [
              "src",         // <--- ADDED THIS
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/web.config"
            ]
```

2) Wrote following service to get the file:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EnvironmentService {
   constructor(private readonly _httpClient: HttpClient) {
   }

   public init(): Promise<any> {       
      return new Promise(resolve =>
         this._httpClient
         .get('file.json')
         .first()
         .subscribe((data: any) => {
            // data from JSON
            resolve()
         })
      )
   }
}
```

**Bonus**:
In case if you want to read custom environment variables(besides what standard Angular one provides) you can add above service into `App.module.ts`:

```
export function init_app(appLoadService: EnvironmentService): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => appLoadService.init()
}

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    EnvironmentService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, deps: [ EnvironmentService ], multi: true },
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

P.S. In case of issues you can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986804/806202).

Comment: Working with a Angular 6 app as well, followed your solution, but wasn't able to retrieve the JSON successfully. I created: [Angular 6: HttpClient Get JSON File 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974020/angular-6-httpclient-get-json-file-404-error) To clarify my situation.

Comment: Shared an answer in your post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986804/806202
I hope it will help.

Comment: where do you put your file.json ?

Comment: In the application source (`src/`) folder.