# Why httpclient in angular 4 is assuming that request am sending json data

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am using angular 4 http client to a server which returns text data so for that I did something like below

```
this.http.get('assets/a.txt').map((res:Response) => 
res.text()).subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data.text());
});
```

I did not tell it any where that the response is in json format but still it is raising the below error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse
>   () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad

On what basis these people assume as the response is in json format :)

Comment: On the basis that that's exactly what it's documented and supposed to do. https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 10):

The Response of new `HttpClient` is JSON by default. If you want to get the response in another format, you can set it via `requestOption` `responseType: 'text'`. Here is some more information about this implementation: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

An example:

```
this.http.get('assets/a.txt', { responseType: 'text' }).map((res:Response) => 
res).subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Nothing mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053328/angular-4-how-to-read-content-of-text-file-with-httpclient but still it is an accepted answer, so is that answer correct only?

Comment: @user2753523 The answer is correct in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053328/angular-4-how-to-read-content-of-text-file-with-httpclient because the problem is that the text file can not be found.