# Angular 6: HttpClient Get JSON File 404 Error

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

Using the HTTP Client, I'm to retrieve a JSON file which resides the `assets` directory within my Angular 6 App which was generated using the CLI. While I know there are a couple related [questions (and answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2) related to this topic, but none have worked in my case.

Below is my file structure:

[image]

Specifically I'm trying to retrieve `us-all-all.geo.json`

`angular.json`

```
 "projects": {
    "ng-ngrx-highcharts-example": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng-ngrx-highcharts-example",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src",
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets/us-all-all.geo.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

`map-data.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { $q } from '@uirouter/angular';

import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapDataService {

  mapData: any;

  mapDataObservable: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  retrieveNationalMapData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('./assets/us-all-all.geo.json');

  }
  retrieveNationalCountyMapDataAssets(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('assets/us-all-all.geo.json');
  }

  retrieveNationalCountyMapDataLocalHost(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/us-all-all.geo.json');
  }
}
```

I call the retrieve function in my component

`highchart-map.component.ts`

```
$q.all([
      this.mapDataService.retrieveNationalMapData().subscribe((nationalMapData) => {
        console.log(nationalMapData);
        mapData.national = nationalMapData;
      }),
      this.mapDataService.retrieveNationalCountyMapDataAssets().subscribe((nationalCountyMapData) => {
        console.log(nationalCountyMapData);
        mapData.national = nationalCountyMapData;
      }),
       this.mapDataService.retrieveNationalCountyMapDataLocalHost().subscribe((nationalCountyMapData) => {
        console.log(nationalCountyMapData);
        mapData.national = nationalCountyMapData;
      })
```

Unfortunately when the app loads I see the following:
[image: Console Error Output]

So at this point I'm not sure what url I should be using to retrieve the JSON.

**EDIT**

[Link to project of GitHub:ng-ngrx-highcharts-example](https://github.com/TYMG/ng-ngrx-highcharts-example/tree/map-charts)

Should I be trying retrieve the JSON from the Dist directory?

[image]

I see that the JSON files located in `src/assets` folder are stored in the `dist/assets` when the app is built.

**Final Edit**

As stated by *user184994*, the issue was my use of the `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` which is intercepting any and all HTTP calls. As a result, I was unable to retrieve my JSON files. After I commented out `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` my gets were working fine, although it breaks my app which utilizes the inMemoryApi

Comment: Have you restarted the server (i.e. stop and call ng-serve again) since adding the JSON file?

Comment: I restarted the server each time I updated the `angular.json` file w/ `ng serve -o`. Also I would delete this dist folder and rebuild using `ng build`

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce the issue... Is this hosted in GitHub or anything where we can take a closer look and run the code?

Comment: `return this.http.get('assets/us-all-all.geo.json')` should have worked fine. It's strange that it's not working that way. I guess it has to do something with the `@uirouter`. Put this function in ngOnint and check if you're able to get a response. That way it can be confirmed if `@uirouter` is involved or not

Comment: Added link to the project Git Repo to original question

Comment: @TYMG If you open http://localhost:4200/assets/us-all-all.geo.json in your browser, can you see the JSON?

Comment: Yes I do, which was one of the first things I looked into when I initially was investigating this issue.

Comment: @TYMG Looks like it's to do with your `app.module`. I've added an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because your `app.module` is importing `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule`, which intercepts any HTTP calls. Instead of trying to get the JSON from your project, it is instead trying to get it from the `InMemoryDataService`.

If you remove this import, it should solve the error, although any calls you have that rely on that module will then fail (such as the `school`, and `national` requests).

Comment: This was the issue! I commented out `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` and the JSON get requests were working. I'll take another crack at retrieving the JSON from `InMemoryDataService` but it's currently 24k + lines... Thanks and Accepted Answer!!

Comment: @TYMG you can configure it to pass through unknown requests, like this: InMemoryDataService, {dataEncapsulation: false, passThruUnknownUrl: true}
, taken from this issue https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/853

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have not defining your path properly since you are in the service folder so you need to change your path {../ which means one step behind}

```
export class MapDataService {

  mapData: any;

  mapDataObservable: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  retrieveNationalMapData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('../../assets/us-all-all.geo.json');

  }
  retrieveNationalCountyMapDataAssets(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('../../assets/us-all-all.geo.json');
  }

}
```

Comment: In the 3rd example (retrieveNationalCountyMapDataLocalHost) it's using the absolute url though...

Comment: no while web pack bundling the code it will check different path

Comment: You can see in the screenshot that it's clearly calling http://localhost:4200/assets/us-all-all.geo.json

Comment: 404 means folder or source not found

Comment: @ChellappanV I tried your solution, changing the Url in the Http.Get to `this.http.get('../../assets/us-all-all.geo.json');`, still 404

Comment: can you  try this one ../../../assets

Comment: Same result unfortunately, but `../../../assets` made more sense because the map-data.service is three directories deep.

Answer (score 1):

Several notes...

After running the server, just do a simple thing: **copy/paste** your resource *URL* into the browser, like this:

[image]

If you see the *JSON* then everything is fine, it means the problem is with how it is requesting from the Angular app. 
To understand the issue open Network section (or console) in your browser, most probably the issue is that how you are requesting the file.

For example, this:   `this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/us-all-all.geo.json');`
will most probably be converted to:
 `http://localhost:4200/http://localhost:4200/assets/us-all-all.geo.json'`.

See my point?

Solution is simply to **call the resource without**
 `http://localshost:4200`,
like:
`this.http.get('assets/us-all-all.geo.json');`