# Reading text file from project

Tags: node.js, angular, fs

I am trying to read a text file from my Angular project (Node version v10.15.3, with Angular 7) using fs.

I installed the fs library using the command:

```
npm install --save fs
```

```js
function readFile(){
const fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFile("src/assets/js/utile/groovy.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
if (err) { console.log(err) }
console.log(data);
})
```

Here is my error message: `Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function`

Comment: `fs` is a Node library for the *server*, not the *client*. Where do you expect that file to be when the app is deployed?

Comment: Ok @jonrsharpe. So any solution about how to do this ? Thks

Comment: Use an HTTP request to read your document, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053328/angular-4-how-to-read-content-of-text-file-with-httpclient) for example.

Comment: Nice @youri let me look into your link and come back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on the comments you cannot use `fs` in the browser as it is meant for server side nodejs.

An alternative is to use an HTTP request to retrieve your text document. This has the benefit of being able to host this text document in another location, like github or another file hosting service.

1. Place your text file in your /assets folder
2. Make sure HttpClientModule is imported in your app.module.ts file
3. Inject HTTPClient to your component or service with

```js
public constructor(
  private http: HTTPClient,
) {}
```

4. Request your file with

```js
this.http.get('/assets/groovy.txt')
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
     }
    }
  );
```

Further reading: https://angular.io/guide/http