# How can I get text from txt URL ? How can I use Filereader from Angular 7?

Tags: angular

“Iwant to get text data from txt url, and fetch it in angular web. How can I get text from txt URL ? How can I use Filereader from Angular 7 ???”

“This is for Angular 7 .”

```
<a (click)="getTextFile()">Check</a>
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpParams,
  HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';




@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-overview-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
 text:any;

  constructor(
     private http: HttpClient,
  ) {

  }


  getTextFile():void{
  this.http.get('https://creamson-intelli.slack.com/files/UFL3QQFP0/FL4N4SNFJ/young_ruskin_bond.txt').subscribe((data) => {
    this.text=data;
    console.log(this.text);
})
}
}
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053328/angular-4-how-to-read-content-of-text-file-with-httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

> [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-http-client-service-demo-vcjjjj?file=app/app.component.html)

service.ts

```
  getRawData(): Observable<any> {
    const api = 'https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt';
    return this.httpClient.get(api,{ responseType: 'text' });    
  }
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  rawlist: any;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  getRawData() {
    this.appService
      .getRawData()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.rawlist=data,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

}
```

.html

```
<button (click)="getRawData()">get raw data </button>

 {{rawlist }}
```

Comment: I don't need any fileuploader from localserver..Is it possible to handle it from server url txt file.??

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://creamson-intelli.slack.com/files/UFL3QQFP0/FL4N4SNFJ/young_ruskin_bond.txt"…}
error: ProgressEvent
headers: HttpHeaders
message: "Http failure response for https://creamson-intelli.slack.com/files/UFL3QQFP0/FL4N4SNFJ/young_ruskin_bond.txt: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://creamson-intelli.slack.com/files/UFL3QQFP0/FL4N4SNFJ/young_ruskin_bond.txt"
__proto__: HttpErrorResponse

Comment: error is syntax that im rerering txt file  check url

Comment: if url is from http://something.com/something/example.txt then error is 

error: ProgressEvent
isTrusted: true
__proto__: ProgressEvent

Comment: @souvicksaha can you sent sample text what you are going to read first of all

Comment: will you please accept my LinkedIn request or send me your mail id ?? For security issue.

Comment: @souvicksaha chanakaweerasinghe92@gmail.com