# How to read a text file from the asset folder in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a text file in the `assets/` folder of my Angular project, and I would like to read its content. I tried also the code below, which unfortunately returns false:

```
let res: boolean = fs.existsSync(join("assets", "foo"));
```

Important to know, I would need this in the main process of my application. Does anyone know what the best method is to read the file? Best is without going through the `this.http` adapter.

Comment: You will have to use `HttpClient` there is no way around it. It's not a node server side application where you can use `fs`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053328/angular-4-how-to-read-content-of-text-file-with-httpclient

Comment: I use Angular in an Electron environment. Would that change my options? But I don't know a way how to get the path where the assets directory is

Comment: the path is simply: `assets/name_of_file`

Comment: @Eliseo, Unfortunately not. fs. file exists check fails