# Simulate http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, http

So currently im programming a front end application with Angular (not really important) and i have a service which currently provides hard coded json data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Client } from '../models/client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientService {

  clientsDataMock : Client[] = [    
    {name: "Client A", id: "15", profiles: [
      {name: "profile1"},
      {name: "profile2"},
      {name: "profile3"}
    ]},
    {name: "Client B", id: "20", profiles: [
      {name: "profileX"}
    ]},
    {name: "Client C", id: "25", profiles: [
      {name: "profileY"}
    ]}
  ];
  constructor() { }

  getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return of(this.clientsDataMock);
  }

  getClient(id : String) : Observable<Client>{
    return of(this.clientsDataMock.find(client => client.id == id));
  }
}
```

Currently the observable doesnt really make much sense and before really connecting all this to the backend i want to load all the data from a different file and kinda simulate the ajax calls or http request, which would be implemented later.

Is there a way to simulate this behavior and fetch the data from a seperate file?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You can make an AJAX call to a static file on the server just like any other AJAX call.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i should have stated the question clearer. I never have made an ajax call or hhtp request, but i probably want to make an ajax call to a static file. @SLaks

Comment: There is no difference between an HTTP request to server-side code and a static file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load json from local file with http.get() in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042223/load-json-from-local-file-with-http-get-in-angular-2) and [how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406043/how-to-fetch-json-file-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through this https://github.com/service-mocker/service-mocker and other such mock API generators.