# Dynamically assigning var to json

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

I have a variable `var locations` in a .ts file and wish to have this equal to a json object in the same folder.  In other words the .json file changes every 5 seconds an I need the variable to update.  I assume that he rxjs observable is they way to go.  I have tried

```
ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, 7000).pipe(
      switchMap( _ => this.hawkerservice.fetchNews()
    )).pipe(
      map((ret:any) => {
       this.locations = ret 
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Now this works well except  `.fetchNews()` pull is over a port with:

```
export class MapjsonService{
  theUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/locations.json';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchNews(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.theUrl)
  }

}
```

So my question is what is the best way to do this without passing the json object over a port.  Namely, just getting it locally.

thx

Comment: your options are really limited. you can either get the file over http by pulling (your currrent use) or by pushng from the server via a websocket.

Comment: I would prefer not to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042223/load-json-from-local-file-with-http-get-in-angular-2  because a simpler solution without http would be preferable

Comment: @SandraWillford it seams like this is a basic functionality angular should have.  It seams counter intuitive to use http if its already on my local machine.

Comment: this is not an Angular issue, this is Javascript. You can either read the JSON file via http get or push it. The other option would be to use an exported object instead of json, but then you would still have to read it on your timer.

Comment: Did you try giving relative path instead? How does it behave?

Comment: you can do something like that @AmitChigadani see the link i posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is as simple as that. Your file is just another resource, which is hosted either `locally` or on `server`. You indeed need `http` to access it, because it is hosted.

Contradicting to your point, you can not simply run your `application` also without using `http`, even though it is hosted `locally`. Same is applicable for `json` file aswell.
You need `http` to access the file.