# Load local json async with httpclient service in Angular

Tags: json, angular, asynchronous, httpclient, angular-services

I'm trying to call load Json with Angular service not on ngOnInit but on a Button on user request. It seams it does load it but does not do it async. I get this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:

I'm new to Angular so pls don't judge.

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at PollComponent.push../src/app/components/poll/poll.component.ts.PollComponent.shuffle (poll.component.ts:23)
    at PollComponent.<anonymous> (poll.component.ts:44)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:68)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at zone.js:741
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:68)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15724
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15772
next @ core.js:17771
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13499
(anonymous) @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17258
onHandleError @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:164
_loop_1 @ zone.js:694
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:703
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:608
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
```

Here is my Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IQuestion } from '../../assets/IData';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PollServiceService {

  private _url: string = "assets/data/TEST_me_50_Pyetje.json";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }

  getQuestions() : Observable<IQuestion[]> {
    return this.http.get<IQuestion[]>(this._url);
   }
}
```

and here is my method. It is called on a button in HTML:

```
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  async startTestClick(){

      var promise = await this.pollService.getQuestions().subscribe(data => this.que = data);
      this.nrSakte = 0;
      this.testQuestions = this.shuffle(this.que).slice(0,50);
      for (let entry of this.testQuestions) {
        entry.picture ="A";
        entry.color = "black";
      }


      let a = await document.getElementsByClassName("alternativa");
      for(let j in a){
        a[j].setAttribute("style", "background-color:#fafafa;");
      }
  }
```

I really want it to wait until the whole Json is loaded so that I can chose which elements to show on HTML. It does show them but it shows this errors. If I want to load dynamically some other json it does not work any more.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023181/6433166

Comment: I did thanks for the reply. It is not the same. It does load the data but it does not do it async. I thought .subscribe() does it async. I just tried to do step 1 and 2 still no change of behaviour. @jpavel

Comment: And about trying to rearrange your code, for example, switching the return type of  `getQuestions()` to a promise `return this.http.get<IQuestion[]>(this._url).toPromise();` => I've noticed you want to use `await` later...

Comment: Please check the shuffle function in PollComponent. That was not given in your post.

Comment: I was trying to use await i really don't need it if it is possible with observable. I just want to fully load the Json( file size 11MB ) and only after to execute this```this.nrSakte = 0;
      this.testQuestions = this.shuffle(this.que).slice(0,50);
      for (let entry of this.testQuestions) {
        entry.picture ="A";
        entry.color = "black";
      }


      let a = document.getElementsByClassName("alternativa");
      for(let j in a){
        a[j].setAttribute("style", "background-color:#fafafa;");
      } ``` @jpavel

Comment: I just checked. It still happens without the shuffle function @GopakumarGopalan

Comment: You have an uncaught error in an async function which could be `startTestClick()` so you may need a `catch()` attached to the function.

Comment: Thanks! If i catch the error the user must click again an the button until the file is loaded. I don't wont that but for the user to wait until the file is fully loaded. @GopakumarGopalan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to move some logic inside the `subscribe` in your call to `startTestClick`.

Something like this:

```
async startTestClick() {

    var promise = await this.pollService.getQuestions().subscribe(data => {
        this.que = data;
        this.nrSakte = 0;
        this.testQuestions = this.shuffle(this.que).slice(0,50);
        for (let entry of this.testQuestions) {
            entry.picture ="A";
            entry.color = "black";
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Without this, the rest of your code is going to run while the `subscribe` is waiting for results, and `this.que` doesn't have anything yet.

I don't think you really need the `async/await`. So, this could work, too.

```
startTestClick() {

    this.pollService.getQuestions().subscribe(data => {
        this.que = data;
        this.nrSakte = 0;
        this.testQuestions = this.shuffle(this.que).slice(0,50);
        for (let entry of this.testQuestions) {
            entry.picture ="A";
            entry.color = "black";
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Then again, you're using an `await` on the `document.getElementsByClassName` call, so I could be wrong. That call may need to be inside the `subscribe`, too.

Try it both ways, see which works. If this doesn't solve your issue, I can delete this answer. This is a bit of a guess based on what's in the post, but *way* too much to put in a comment.