# Trying to load local json file in Angular8

Tags: angular8

I'm trying to load local json file but I keep getting an error:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 getJsonFIle() {

    this.http.get("./configs/dor.json").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the error on the browser:

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are your dor.json placed?

Comment: src\app\configs\dor.json

Comment: you need to put it into assets and change the path to the `/assets/configs/dor.json`

Comment: or you need to add path `"src/configs"` into angular.json file in "assets" array

Comment: Found the answer here.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042223/load-json-from-local-file-with-http-get-in-angular-2)