# Importing error on a JSON file at the same folder level - Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, angular8

I am experiencing a couple of strange errors regarding reading a json file through an Angular service. 
Up to now, every json file that I found on my street I read in Angular8 using an `http` call, like this:

```
this.http.get('bibliographic_citation_childs.json').subscribe(response => {
  console.log('here is the content!', response);
});
```

The absurd thing is that the error is that I have an error in console like this:
`zone-evergreen.js:2952 GET http://localhost:4205/bibliographic_citation_childs.json 404 (Not Found)`

But how is it possible?
The folder hierarchy is structured in this way, it is unequivocal:
[image]
I also tried to strengthen directionally using the path:

```
'src/app/services/xml-parsers/bibliography-parser-service/bibliographic_citation_childs.json'
```

and

```
'./bibliographic_citation_childs.json'
```

but nothing. Any other http call I make to any other json file in the project works for me, it doesn't want to work. I can't understand why. 
Is there anything I don't know?

Comment: Check this answer hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023181/5480425

Comment: May you be blessed!

Comment: I’m glad to have helped