# http get from assets not work in published app Angular 9

Tags: json, angular, file, http, get

i worked with Angular +9 and i've a problem when read json file from assets folder.

i am using the http module and the call works fine when the application is run locally, but when i run ng-build and publish the application on a server, the call to the json file doesn't work indicating the following message:

> ERROR Http failure response for assets/resources/fakeData.json: 0 Unknown Error

My code:

[image: call http request to json file]

What could be the problem? Why can't I access the assets folder directly?

Comment: Any error in the browser console? Have a look at the network tab to check exact url called

Comment: this is the most detailed error i managed to find

error =>  https://ibb.co/ft3cvRv

and in the network window, the request have "canceled" status

Comment: What's your web server?  How did you configure it? Maybe try with `/assets`? Status of 0 is usually for CORS errors, but I don't think it's the case here

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access your *file system* with the `HttpClient`. You can't do that. You could of course make an API Endpoint that returns your json file, but you can't access it directly like that with the `HttpClient` module.

Here what I would do instead:

```
import * as myJson from '<path to fakeData.json>';
...
getData(): any {
   return myJson;
}
```

If you are just trying to mess around with `HttpClient` module and need some json to play with, you use [JSON Placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) API:

`this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');`

According to the below SOF Question, it looks like you can get your local json files to be hosted along with the angular dev server if you wanted to:

[Load json from local file with http.get() in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042223/load-json-from-local-file-with-http-get-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which web server you are using, but it looks like your web server does not support hosting of JSON-files.

- Apache: use the AddType directive - https://cets.seas.upenn.edu/answers/addtype.html
- IIS: Add a MIME-type - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap